# How to override _prepareCollection and _prepareColumns in Magento Admin

Tags: magento, overriding

How to override _prepareCollection and _prepareColumn from core to local. I want to add new column in a grid. How to do this?

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
  {
      $collection = Mage::getModel('players/players')->getCollection();
      $this->setCollection($collection);
      return parent::_prepareCollection();
  }


protected function _prepareColumns()
  {
      $this->addColumn('player_id', array(
          'header'    => Mage::helper('players')->__('ID'),
          'align'     =>'right',
          'width'     => '50px',
          'index'     => 'player_id',
      ));

      $this->addColumn('name', array(
          'header'    => Mage::helper('players')->__('Name'),
          'align'     =>'left',
          'index'     => 'name',
      ));    

      return parent::_prepareColumns();
  }
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Are you trying to add to an existing grid? If so, which one?

Comment: Yes i am trying to add a column in existing grid(sales/orders).

Answer (score 8):

Well there are two ways to do it.  The first, while easier is not preferred, is to "local include hack" it and move the grid from core/Mage/../.. to local/Mage../.. and simply make your changes are required.

The alternative is to do a rewrite of the file in a module config.xml:

```
    <blocks>
        <customadminhtml>
            <class>Namespace_CustomAdminhtml_Block</class>
        </customadminhtml>
        <adminhtml>
            <rewrite>
                <sales_order_grid>Namespace_CustomAdminhtml_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Grid</sales_order_grid>
            </rewrite>
        </adminhtml>
    </blocks>
```

In the rewritten file I would not both trying to override the "_prepareCollection" call.  How are you going to call it and set the collection, logically, you can't insert your changes in there properly and still maintain original functionality. Instead I would override the "setCollection" method.  By doing this you maintain the logic of the original _prepareCollection function and can insert your logic into the flow:

```
/**
* @brief Add customer_email to sales order
* @param Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_order_grid_collection $collection
*/
public function setCollection($collection)
{
    /** @var Mage_Eav_Model_Config $eav */
    $eav       = Mage::getModel('eav/config');
    $attribute = $eav->getAttribute('customer', 'customer_number');

    $connection = $collection->getConnection();
    $collection->join(array('sfo' => 'sales/order'), 'main_table.entity_id=sfo.entity_id', 'customer_email');

    if ($attribute->getId()) {
        $collection->getSelect()
            ->joinLeft(array('c' => $connection->getTableName('customer_entity_varchar')),
                       'main_table.customer_id = c.entity_id AND c.attribute_id = '.$attribute->getId(),
                       array('customer_number' => 'value'));
    }

    parent::setCollection($collection);
}
```

Finally, you can add the column by overriding the normal "_prepareColumns" function, just call the parent before hand:

```
public function _prepareColumns()
{
    parent::_prepareColumns();

    $this->addColumnAfter('customer_email', array(
                                                 'header' => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Customer Email'),
                                                 'width'  => '50px',
                                                 'index'  => 'customer_email',
                                            ), 'shipping_name');

    $this->sortColumnsByOrder();
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: This is good, however when I do "filter by status" in my custom order grid, I get `Call to a member function setColumn() on boolean`, I have added `'filter' => 'custom_name'` too. Any idea about this?